# Risks of developer signing credentials

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4

According to the Identityserver4 documentation the AddDeveloperSigningCredential is, as the name implies, for development purposes only. I have found several articles that describe the process of switching to other signing certificates that are more geared towards production environments. My question is why is the switch necessary? Are the generated developer signing credentials insecure in some way, and if so what is the attack vector that can be exploited? What if I am running my identity server through an nginx reverse proxy and using an aws cloud signing credential through a load balancer? Does that adequately resolve the exposed attack vector? In short what risks are there to using developer signing credentials in production?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generated RSA key (2k) is from a security point of view totally fine - you won't get "bad crypto" compared to a "production key".

The main problem with the dev signing key is that it is loaded from the local hard-disk - and especially (by default) from the application directory.

You should have a more secure storage location for keys (e.g. the Windows certificate store or some storage service) so that in case an attacker can read files from the app server hard disk cannot easily recover the private key.

Comment: I wish I had the reputation to up vote this. Thank you, it clears that up rather nicely.